# How to remove the transparency of a popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup in my MVC application to show notification to user and the code as follows

```
<span class="noti glyphicon glyphicon-bell"><span class="count">&nbsp;</span></span>
                    <div class="noti-content">
                        <div class="noti-top-arrow"></div>
                        <ul id="notiContent"></ul>
                    </div>
```

---

CSS as below

```
<style type="text/css">

        .noti-content {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            background: #e5e5e5;
            border-radius: 4px;
            top: 47px;
            width: 250px;
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid #9E988B;
        }

        ul#notiContent {
            max-height: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

            ul#notiContent li {
                margin: 3px;
                padding: 6px;
                background: #fff;
            }

        .noti-top-arrow {
            border-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: #F5DEB3;
            border-style: dashed dashed solid;
            border-width: 0 8.5px 8.5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 32px;
            top: -8px;            
        }

        span.noti {
            color: #FF2323;
            margin: 15px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            font-size: 18px;
            cursor: pointer;            
        }

        span.count {
            position: relative;
            top: -3px;
        }
    </style>
```

---

When I open the popup, the popup looks transparent and the background content can be seen which are behind the popup background.

Could you please any one can tell me how to remove the transparency of the popup and prevent the background content can be seen through popup.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or any working code snippet?

Comment: add background: rgba(0,0,0,1);

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your help, with the help of yours I managed to correct it after adding                                                                                                   z-index: 1 !important; to Div